# Complex Ruby SQL query using Active Record - WHERE using OR clause and subquery

Tags: sql, ruby, activerecord

I am using Ruby 2.0.0, and Rails 4.1.0.

I am struggling to translate a complex SQL query to Ruby. I was able to convert most of it, but I am having a hard time with the "OR" clause.

Here is the original SQL query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT "lecture_classes".* 
FROM "lecture_classes" 
INNER JOIN 
    "lectures" ON "lectures"."id" = "lecture_classes"."lecture_id" 
INNER JOIN 
    "weeks" ON "weeks"."id" = "lectures"."week_id"  
WHERE "lectures"."part" = 1 
    AND "weeks"."number" = 1 
    AND "weeks"."course_id" = 1 
    AND(                                          --very important parenthesis start
        "lecture_classes"."id" IN (
        SELECT "lecture_enrollments"."lecture_class_id" 
        FROM "lecture_enrollments"  
        GROUP BY lecture_class_id 
        HAVING count(lecture_class_id) <= 5
        ) 
        OR "lecture_classes"."id"                --this is the OR that needs to have Ruby equivalent
        NOT IN (
            SELECT "lecture_enrollments"."lecture_class_id"
            FROM "lecture_enrollments"
            )  
    )                                           --very important parenthesis ends
ORDER BY "lecture_classes"."class_date" ASC
```

I was able to convert most of it:

```
@max_students = 5

LectureClass
       .joins(:lecture, lecture: :week)
       .where(lectures: {part: part})
       .where(weeks: {number: week, course_id: course})
       .where(id: LectureEnrollment
                  .select("lecture_class_id")
                  .group("lecture_class_id")
                  .having("count(lecture_class_id) <= ?",@max_students)
                  )
       .distinct
       .order(class_date: :asc)
```

but my biggest struggle is including the "OR" clause... and note that it needs to be inside the parenthesis with the other clause (noted in the comment), otherwise the result is wrong.

I know I can do something like

```
Project.where("manager_user_id = ? OR account_manager = ?", current_user.id, current_user.id)
```

But my problem is I don't have the OR value, it is the result of a select statement. How to write that in Ruby?

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

*** UPDATE:

Thanks Drew, that works!

I tried to make it more pretty and Ruby-like based on your previous response, so I did

```
@max_students = 5 

LectureClass
       .joins(:lecture, lecture: :week)
       .where(lectures: {part: part})
       .where(weeks: {number: week, course_id: course})
       .where(id: LectureEnrollment
                  .select("lecture_class_id")
                  .group("lecture_class_id")
                  .having("count(lecture_class_id) <= ?",@max_students)
                  )
       .or( LectureClass
            .where
            .not(id:[LectureEnrollment
                          .select(:lecture_class_id)
                     ])
            )
       .distinct
       .order(class_date: :asc)
```

However I get an error saying NoMethodError - undefined method `or'. I guess that is a arel dependent method (https://github.com/rails/arel), but I dont want to add this library just to solve the OR problem. The SQL mix works great. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about the following?

```
LectureClass
       .joins(:lecture, lecture: :week)
       .where(lectures: {part: part})
       .where(weeks: {number: week, course_id: course})
       .where("lecture_classes.id IN (
        SELECT lecture_class_id
        FROM lecture_enrollments 
        GROUP BY lecture_class_id 
        HAVING count(lecture_class_id) <= ?
        ) 
        OR lecture_classesid
        NOT IN (
            SELECT lecture_class_id
            FROM lecture_enrollments
            )", @max_students)
       .distinct
       .order(class_date: :asc)
```